# How to change the default path separator in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, path-separator

I have cross-platform projects, which I have to compile with GCC, Clang and MSVC. Whenever I use the Visual Studio's and type `#include <foo...`, IntelliSense suggests `\` as the path separator. This obviously works on MSVC, but on GCC and other compilers triggers an error.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to use `/` instead?

Comment: I'm fairly sure changing this is the same for all Visual Studio versions since it was introduced, so it might be worth editing the tags and title as to be less specific to the 2015 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows:

1. Go to "Tools → Options… → Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced"
2. Toggle "Use Forward Slash in #include Auto Complete" under the "IntelliSense" section